# NSView background layer

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, layer

Can;t figure out the answer yet, but I have this code which is called for a view:

```
func gradient(fillView view: NSView, withGradientFromColors colors: Array<NSColor>) {

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds

let color1 = colors[0].cgColor
let color2 = colors[1].cgColor
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

view.layer?.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

This code takes two values of NSColor and should create a gradient background.

The code works! Buut, if i try to execute something else on this view for example i have a label on top of it which needs to be shown, it's actually not shown after this code is executed. I believe it is somehow behind the view that i draw?

Any fast way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the adding of sublayer as below:

```
view.layer?.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just what i was looking for, solution was even easier than i thought! KUDOS!